# How to prevent Coldfusion from injecting cfform.js into the head section?

Tags: templates, coldfusion, code-injection

An HTML template is passed to Coldfusion. The head tag of the template has additional attribute:

```
<head profile="http://abc.com">
```

The issue is that when generating the output based on this template Coldfusion injects its scripts inside the head tag:

```
<head <script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/cfform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/masks.js"></script>
profile="http://abc.com">
```

This causes `profile="http://abc.com">` to appear on the top of the page and prevents page from validation.

The code injection occurs only when there is a form tag. The wrong-place injection does not happen if the head tag does not have any attributes. The presence of the attribute is a project requirement and cannot be omitted.

Is it possible to prevent Coldfusion from injecting the scripts?

Comment: Definitely a ColdFusion bug.  You can report it to adobe here: https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform&product=7

Comment: If you submit the bug report, you may also want to include this link to show that a profile attribute in the head tag is perfectly valid HTML: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_head.asp

Comment: @Kip Thanks for the suggestion. Have just submitted a bug to Adobe.

Comment: @Alex - IIRC, I _think_ custom tags might offer a way around the placement issue. While far from ideal, would a custom tag hack help here at all: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/472576  ?

Comment: @Henry - Both. At least it does under 9,0,0,241018.

Comment: Whilst HTML5 is no longer supporting profile attribute [http://www.w3schools.com/tags/html5_head.asp], the bug still occurs for any other legitimate attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script injection only happens for cfforms, not standard forms.  If you aren't using any of cfform's enhancements, you can simply switch to a standard form.

I checked the cumulative hotfix list, and didn't see a fix for this.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the suggestion. That's what probably I'll end up doing. I'm so not looking forward rewriting the existing code. Do you know if this issue is listed as a bug anywhere?

Comment: I don't know if there is a public bug listing.  I'd suggest you submit it, as Kip suggested.

Comment: There is a public bug tracker here: http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html

Comment: it really sucks that coldfusion does this, I am running into the same issue on legacy code.  epic fail.

Answer (score 2):

My Solution:  Put the meta tag right after the

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<head>
```

when CF creates the page it puts the tag below the  but above the  tags

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class=" ext-strict">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */_cf_loadingtexthtml="<img alt=' ' src='/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/cf/images/loading.gif'/>";
_cf_contextpath="";
_cf_ajaxscriptsrc="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax";
_cf_jsonprefix='//';
_cf_clientid='9851DA49BD375D9722A9D6B1951976AC';/* ]]> */</script><<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/yui/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
```