# Profile element visible in browser

Tags: html, profile, head

I have found that the profile element of my head is showing up in the browser.  The interesting thing is that it is only doing this for one page in particular, even though I have the profile element on every page of our website.  The code is:  and the link to the page it is occurring on is: http://www.oilpaintersofamerica.com/memberservices/contactmembership.cfm

Any ideas?

Comment: I came across this same issue here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477266/how-to-prevent-coldfusion-from-injecting-cfform-js-into-the-head-section

It seems that ColdFusion injects code into the head of the document when using CFForm, which can cause any attributes to be displayed in the browser.

The only solution I have come across is to either remove the attribute, or not use CFForm.

I have submitted a bug to Adobe:
http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=85799

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `<script>` tags inside the `<head ...>` start tag, before the `profile` attribute.
The browser tries to fix this by closing the start tag.

Therefore, it ends up parsing the literal text `profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">`
 inside your `<head>`.
For (I assume) compatibility reasons, any literal text inside the `<head>` is rendered in the page.

You need to fix your `<head>`.